# Can electromagnetic fields "retain" records?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

Electromagnetic waves that are moving can send records such as data that are converted into images.

But could a static electromagnetic field somehow retain information in itself? (Without the need for any form of device)

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Flash memory stores information in the form of charges stored (or not stored) in an array of special transistors. The information can equivalently be thought of as being stored in the static electric field that results. A hard disk drive similarly stores information in the magnetic field.

If these don't meet your "no device" criterion, you could store information using the same principle by storing (or not) charges in a number of predetermined locations, or encoding it in the orientations of a number of magnetic dipoles.

If no charges or magnetic dipoles are allowed, Maxwell's equations do permit a limited set of static background fields, which we don't observe, and in any case it would be hard to interpret them as containing information, especially given that you would have no control over them.

Answer (score 3):

Without any device electromagnetic waves move through space at the speed of light. So they can store information, but the information is moving in space at the speed of light.

Using an optical cavity device, light can be stored between mirrors. In this way information in a light field can be made to stay in one spot in space, at least for micro- or milli-seconds.